# ASP.NET MVC3 Invalid object name 'Locations_tracking'

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4.1

I have an MVC3 application that I received from another developer.  I have set up the correct database and added it to my Web.config.  There is a model and controller called Location(s).

The controller and view to add a location is very standard CRUD, yet when I try to add a location, the Create method throws this:

```
Invalid object name 'Locations_tracking'.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web     request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object name 'Locations_tracking'.

Source Error: 


Line 56:                 location.UpdatedAt = DateTime.Now;
Line 57:                 db.Locations.Add(location);
Line 58:                 db.SaveChanges();
Line 59:                 return RedirectToAction("Index");  
Line 60:             }
```

I have searched for "tracking" in my entire application and don't find anything.  Why is it looking for this "Locations_tracking" object and why can't it find it?  I assume it is coming from Entity Framework since I don't see anything in the controller, model or views.  Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for a trigger on the Locations table.  Given the naming of the missing table here, I'm thinking that it's an audit table for inserts and updates that is fed by a trigger.  If so, you probably have the trigger, but not the table.

Comment: That's exactly what it was.  This database had been prepared for MS Sync Framework, which added the triggers and extra tables.  The previous admin deleted the tracking tables, but not the triggers.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is a SQL exception. It looks like it is trying to update/insert into the table `Locations_tracking` which doesn't exist. In addition to inheriting the application did you also inherit SQL scripts that would allow you to create the database structure that this application relies upon?